# Cannot find openam-oauth2-common 13.0.0 version

Tags: maven, openam, oauth-2.0

We are upgrading `openam` to version **`13`**. I've set artifacts version to `13.0.0` but when I start building the service with Maven I get a error message saying:

> failure to find `org.forgerock.openam:openam-oauth2-common:jar:13.0.0`.

We are using forgerock repository: http://maven.forgerock.org/repo/repo/

**Question**: why the dependency is suddendly not available any longer and how to properly upgrade it?

Comment: Can you share more of your `pom.xml` file? the artifact you are looking for is not a `jar` file, it's a `pom`. How are you using it?

Comment: <dependency>
                <groupId>org.forgerock.openam</groupId>
                <artifactId>openam-oauth2-common</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
                <version>13.0.0</version>
            </dependency>

Comment: from which version are you upgrading?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the artifact you were using has been refactored, moving from a single project (i.e. a library) to a multi-module project (several modules, several libraries). Hence, although its Maven coordinates have not changed (GAV, GroupId, ArtifactId, Version), the usage (the consumption) of this library has been directly affected because its **type** has changed (again, from `jar` to `pom`).

Version `11.0.0`, for example, was a [**jar**](http://maven.forgerock.org/repo/repo/org/forgerock/openam/openam-oauth2-common/11.0.0/), hence you could import it as most of the Maven dependency, via a `dependency` section.

However, since version `12.0.0`, the artifact is a [**pom**](http://maven.forgerock.org/repo/repo/org/forgerock/openam/openam-oauth2-common/12.0.0/) defining the following modules:

```
<module>oauth2-core</module>
<module>oauth2-restlet</module>
<module>openid-connect-core</module>
<module>openid-connect-restlet</module>
<module>oauth2-oidc-test-server</module>
```

Hence, what previously would have been:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.forgerock.openam</groupId>
    <artifactId>openam-oauth2-common</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <version>11.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

It cannot be simply upgraded via its version number but must be replaced via several dependencies (you can now narrow down what you actually need):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.forgerock.openam</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth2-core</artifactId>
    <version>13.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.forgerock.openam</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth2-restlet</artifactId>
    <version>13.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.forgerock.openam</groupId>
    <artifactId>openid-connect-core</artifactId>
    <version>13.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.forgerock.openam</groupId>
    <artifactId>openid-connect-restlet</artifactId>
    <version>13.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.forgerock.openam</groupId>
    <artifactId>oauth2-oidc-test-server</artifactId>
    <version>13.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Most probably version `11.0.0` is provided as a subset of the dependencies above, including them should fix the issue (but you could also investigate later on which one is effectively required by your project, e.g. the last one, `oauth2-oidc-test-server`, is most probably not required simply looking at its artifactId name, as an immediate guess).

Comment: @XXLUser did this answer help you out? you didn't share any further feedback nor accept it. Just checking